# Will a 300W UPS work fine if my PSU is 500W?

Tags: power-supply, power-management, power, ups

I am getting a UPS (Uninterrupted Power Supply), currently here are my options:

- http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE500R-PH
- https://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BR500CI-AS
- http://www.fsplifestyle.com/ups/line-interactive/ep-850/#specifications

They all seem to have less than 500W. I was wondering if they will work fine with my 500W PSU?
In terms of price they are all the same (around $60) and I am not really sure about their differences.

I hope you can also recommended what's best between them. I am using a mid-end gaming rig BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To definitely answer this question, you will need to use something like a [Kill A Watt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009MDBU), which will tell you that actual amount of electricty you are using.  The amount that you are using really depends on your hardware components such a CPU, # of hard drives & RPM speeds, graphics cards, etc.

The first two UPSs look the same to me as far as specs go and the last URL won't load for me.

Answer (score 0):

They will work just fine with your computer. Note the Batteries & Runtime graph on the APC site. You are probably looking at a usage of about 200-300W on your computer, so that gives you 5 min of battery time.

You should look at the product groups (https://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=27&tab=models). Under "Model list" chose 500W and you can see the estimated time under it. I would recomend at least a  540 Watts / 900 VA model.